# TCP/IP in C connection value re assigning

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am working on TCP/IP project (Server, and many clients). I wrote code completely in C. I have observed that whenever a new client connects to the server, function `accept()` returns a number for that particular connection.

```
  newton = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize)
```

`newcon` in the above code is different for different clients. Whenever a client disconnects, the connection number which was assigned to that disconnected client is gone. That number is not going to get assigned to another client at all. if the server has many users then clients connect and disconnect lot of times. so the number go on increasing (from 0 to bigger number). How should I deal with this if the server has millions of clients connected? Is there any way that I can reuse the connection number again?

Comment: `That number is not going to get assigned to another client at all.` wrong. The accept() system call returns the lowest available file descriptor for the new connection. So the fd (numbers)  are recycled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand the return value of `accept`. It is not a number of connections, but a socket descriptor. (Which happens to be file descriptor, which is integer, on *nix platforms).

The same number can be returned again if one of the previously assigned sockets is closed - so, in order to maintain your scalability, make sure you close your sockets after they are no longer needed - which is a proper thing to do anyways.

Comment: I know it is not the number of connections. Every time a new client connects to server, I get a new value. every number I get is not a previous number which is less than that number. The problem might be not closing the disconnected client. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Test it.

Create an array of integers, say 10000 in size. When you accept a connection, push the fd value returned into that array. Then at the end, sort the array and look for duplicates. You should see duplicates, as others have alluded to.

Comment: Good Idea to test.

Answer (score 0):

The server side implementation of a TCP connection is designed to support multiple concurrent connections. This behavior is achieved using the accept() system call which is invoked with the server socket as parameter. When a new connection requests arrives, the system creates a new socket to handle this new connection and this socket descriptor is returned by the accept system call. Subsequently the communication on this new connection is handled using this socket descriptor returned by accept. When the communication with client is completed, the connection is closed and this socket descriptor is returned to the system. The system can reuse the same descriptor again to handle a new client request again.

It should be noted that once the connection is closed, in certain conditions the connection moves to TIME_WAIT state and the socket is not re-used when the connection state is TIME_WAIT. The socket becomes free after the TIME_WAIT state. So this is quite possible that when one connection is assumed to be closed, it can actually be in TIME_WAIT state. This can be verified using 'netstat -anp' command.

Socket descriptors are system resources and each system has an upper limit on maximum number of open descriptors. Once that limit is reached, the system does not accept new connections. So if a client-server system has been implemented in such a way that there are not large number of concurrent TCP connections, the limit of maximum number of open descriptors is not hit and server will continue to server the clients. If the client-server system requires large number of persistent connections then definitely the limit of open descriptors can be a problem and will need to be increased.

Comment: "Socket descriptors are system resources and each system has an upper limit on maximum number of open descriptors", How do we know the maximum number of possible connections?

Comment: The system-wide limit of maximum number of open file descriptors on Linux can be checked using command "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max". This limit can be modified using sysctl command on parameter fs.file-max.

Answer (score -1):

*accept* returns a descriptor. You could implement a data structure, where you could store the descriptors and manipulate them. But it depends on the use case and your implementation and what you are going to do with them.